# Mongoose find() method not working with query parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find a particular document in mongodb  using Node Js and mongoose .

But when I'm running following code snippet I'm getting no response from database.

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Vehicle = require("../db/models/vehicle");

//api to get single vehicle data
router.get("/vehicle", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { name } = req.query;
    console.log(name);
    const vehicle = await Vehicle.find({ name: name });
    res.status(200).json(vehicle);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error });
  }
});
```

[postman image with no response][1]

But when I'm running following code snippet I'm getting  response from database.

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Vehicle = require("../db/models/vehicle");

//api to get single vehicle data
router.get("/vehicle", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
  
    const vehicle = await Vehicle.find({ name: "BMW II" });
    res.status(200).json(vehicle);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error });
  }
});
```

[postman image with response][2]
What should I do ?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7svLJ.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgxRa.png

Comment: Maybe the the route path needs to be "/test/api/vehicle".

Comment: try removing the quotes from BMW II

Comment: In the first code snippet what does `console.log(name);` print? Do you actually get a valid name in your request?

Comment: yes i get name variable value which I pass in query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen by [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7svLJ.png) You are sending your query as `name="BMW II"` then in the server your name variable will be set to `'"BMW II"'` Therefore you will not get the correct results.

```js
//your req will have a field like this
req = {query: { name: '"BMW II"' },...}
```

when sending query strings you do not enclose in quotes even though it is string. query strings in express are by default identified as strings in the backend.
just send in like `name=BMW II` and your name variable will be set to `'BMW II'`.

```js
req = {query: { name: 'BMW II' },...}
```

In case you are sending a number as a query string say `num=5` Then in the backend you will have parse it to an integer if you are willing to do calculations on it since it is received as string from `req.query`

```js
req = {query: { num: '5' },...}
```